# SQL Server Express 2008 R2 on HomeGroup setup

Tags: sql-server-2008

Its a shame that I've been a developer for so many years but never got to do network setup.

Will I be able setup an SQL Server Express R2 and connect from one PC to another with a HomeGroup setup? If so, how?

Comment: Both are Windows 7. Do I need to configure something on my SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, following may be a good starting point http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx - different version but I can't recall much changing, in your case I'd probably enable the browser service it'll make things easier to follow and shouldn't be remotely accessible (assuming your Internet router doesn't have all incoming ports open).

Comment: I thought all this time I would need to set the Home Group first before I can remotely connect to an SQL instance. It seems that I dont need to. Two pcs connected via hub is enough